# Copy constructor for every derived class

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, copy-constructor

Consider the following code.  I want the `convert` function to work without defining the `T(const Base&)` copy constructor in every concrete derived type of `Base`.
It could be done in the intermediate class `CRTP<T>` in the way illustrated only if it is not abstract, but it is abstract.  So how can I make it work in this case?

```
struct Base {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct CRTP : virtual Base {
    CRTP (const Base& base) : Base(base) { }
    CRTP() = default;
//  virtual void foo() override { }  // CRTP<T> is abstract.
};

struct Derived1 : CRTP<Derived1> {
    Derived1 (const Base& base) : Base(base) { }
    Derived1() = default;
    virtual void foo() override { }
};

struct Derived2 : CRTP<Derived1> {
    Derived2 (const Base& base) : Base(base) { }
    Derived2() = default;
    virtual void foo() override { }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
T* convert (const U& u) {
//  return new T(u);  // This works, but only if T(const Base&) constructor is defined in every Base concrete derived type.
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(new CRTP<T>(u));  // This only works if CRTP<T> is not abstract.
}

int main() {
    Derived1 d1;
    Derived2* d = convert<Derived2, Derived1>(d1);
}
```

Comment: There's not much sense to mixup static with dynamic polymorphism despite some very special cases. Can you please elaborate about the real use case you want to solve with this? Looks like a xy-problem for me.

Comment: Minor point about terminology: `T(const Base&)` is not a copy constructor. A copy constructor takes an argument of the type being constructed: `T(T&)`, `T(const T&)` `T(volatile T&)`, or `T(const volatile T&)`.

Comment: For polymorphic "copy constructor" (and being a good modern C++ citizen), the usual idiom is to have a `virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const;` so the derived classes can gin-up a copy of themselves via `auto p = q->clone();`, and probably use their own actual copy constructor in the process.

Answer (score 0):

But, as a matter of fact, it is not a copy constructer, so it could be simply delegated like this:

```
struct Derived1 : CRTP<Derived1> {
    using CRTP<Derived1>::CRTP;
    Derived1() = default;
    virtual void foo() override {
    }
};
```

You can also use a pointer instead of a reference, which seems more relevant in your code by the way, because convert() returns a pointer. Such constructor is not considered as a copy constructor and can always be delegated to the children.